# Read in memory and inc (6502)

Tags: 6502

Sorry if the question seems to be 'too basic'. I'm a 68K ASM coder but one friend ask me for a glance at a piece of 6502 code.
We have a pointer to a string of data:

```
 my_ptr ds 2
```

This pointer is set with this code:

```
ldx sound_channel_busy
bne .abc_set_score1   ; at bottom of code
sta my_ptr   ; fill the pointer
```

Reading data is done with

```
lda (my_ptr),y    ; my_ptr + offset
```

But as I see in the 6502 doc, y is one byte. So with that, it's not possible to use a data string of more than 255 bytes which is not enought (we want to read strings of 10.000 bytes or more.
I suggest my friend to do that:

1) Set one pointer as "base" and a temporary one which we'll inc while reading

```
 my_ptr ds 2
 my_ptr_tmp ds 2
```

2) Init them with:

```
ldx sound_channel_busy
bne .abc_set_score1
sta my_ptr
sta my_ptr_tmp  ; Duplicate
```

3) Then read using:

```
  lda (my_ptr_tmp)   ; Read to acumulator
  inc my_ptr_tmp     ; One more on adress pointer
```

But it don't work and as my friend is a C dev, and we don't have debugger... not easy.
In 68K this seems to be logical but in 6502?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I upvote this because of using 'too basic' in question regarding machine language. LOL. Pun intended?

Answer (score 7):

6502 is quite limited.

- All reads and writes to memory are 8 bit
- All arithmetic is 8 bit
- There are only two indirect modes: `(zp),y` and `(zp,x)` wherer `zp` is a zero page address. The former calculates the address as

  ```
  contentOf(zp + (zp + 1) << 8) + y
  ```

  and uses the byte at it as the operand. The latter calculates the address as

  ```
  contentOf( zp + x + (zp + x + 1) << 8)
  ```

The y form is used for accessing elements of arrays pointed to by the zero page pointer and the x form is used for accessing vector tables in zero page memory.

To set up the pointer:

```
    lda #<pointer ; The low byte of the 16 bit address pointer is loaded into A
    sta my_ptr
    lda #>pointer ; the high byte of the pointer
    sta my_ptr+1
    ldy #0        ; zero the y register
```

To access the pointer

```
loopStart:
    lda (my_ptr),y
```

Assuming a C style string with a null terminator

```
    beq loopExit  ; previous LDA sets the S and Z flags.
```

To increment the pointer

```
    iny           ; Increment y
    bne loopStart
    inc my_ptr+1
    jmp loopStart
```

You could also do it keeping Y as 0 and incrementing the low byte and the two zero page locations, but `INC my_ptr` is much slower than `INY` taking five cycles instead of two.

**Edit**

If, instead of a null terminated string, you have a length, you'll need to modify this slightly. One way is to count how many bytes you have done and compare with the length. With the algorithm above, Y is the count, if the length < 256, so what we can do is store the high byte of the count in

```
; first set up my_ptr, same as before.
; 
    lda #<pointer ; The low byte of the 16 bit address pointer is loaded into A
    sta my_ptr
    lda #>pointer ; the high byte of the pointer
    sta my_ptr+1
;
;   Set up the counter
;
    ldx #0        ; set up x for the count
    ldy #0        ; Set up y for the count/loop
;
;   A common trick with compiling while loops is to put the test at the end of the loop and jump to it immediately. 
;  This means you don't have to reverse the logic of the loop condition.
;
    jmp loopTest  ; Omit this if you definitely need to go round the loop at least once
loopStart:
    lda (my_ptr),y    ; Get the byte
;
;   Do what you need to do here
;
;   Increment the counter
;
    iny           ; Increment y
    bne loopTest
    inx
    inc my_ptr+1
loopTest:
    cpy length    ; Compare the low byte of length to the count
    bne loopStart
    cpx length+1  ; Compare the high byte of length to the count
    bne loopStart
```

Comment: The idea of using y and in case o 0, inc the pointer seems to be a nice tricks. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to claim I thought of it, but back in the day, it was a very common technique for 6502 programming.

Answer (score 1):

6502 is 8-bit data, 16-bit address, so your pointers need to be 2 bytes, usually in page zero.

```
lda #<addr ;low byte
sta my_ptr
sta my_ptr_tmp
lda #>addr ;high byte
sta my_ptr+1
sta my_ptr_tmp+1
```

The inc also needs to be 16-bit:

```
inc my_ptr_tmp
bne :skip
inc my_ptr_tmp+1 ;only inc high byte if low byte is zero
:skip
```

Also, note that lda (zp) without X or Y is only available on 65C02.

Comment: Hmmm... In the first part of your answer this means you read 2 bytes. But in my case I have a 2 bytes adresse from which I want to read only one. So I think the problem came from tne inc of the adress (which you explain in secon part of your answer). Am I right? (I'll try and come back) . Thanks a lot.

Comment: So this mean the move.word in 68K must be done here with two move byte. For copying the prt and also to inc it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct from what you've said. Is the data bytes or words? As you can see, 65(C)02 code is almost RISC, so the code really changes (register use etc) depending on context. If you elaborate on your use case I could flesh out my sample code. For instance, if the data is not zero terminated (likely the case if sound samples) decrementing a two byte counter might be needed.

Comment: Adress pointer is word (my_ptr) and data is byte. So each time we read one byte. And data are zero terminated. I've made the change according to your idea (use y and when it come back to 0, in prt+1) and it seems to work. Unfortunalty the code as other bugs so we're investigating.